# Is "What you desire is what you get" a simple sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"What you desire is what you get." 
Is it a simple sentence?

My hunch is it's a simple sentence, although it only partially fits into Randolph Quirk's idea, stated in his A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, of a simple sentence containing a subordinate clause. For Quirk, a simple sentence can contain a subordinate clause provided that clause functions not as a sentence element (S, O, C, A etc.) but as a clausal modifier of a head within a phrase. For example: "This is the car that Jack owns." In the original question, however, two subordinate clauses function as two sentence elements (Subject, Subject complement).